# Vtiger login page not showing

Tags: apache2, vtiger

everytime I try to access: localhost/vtiger, it only shows a blank page. I actually have another web app (openatrium) on /var/www/ which is completely working.

I've added an entry on sites-available, I tried (which seems to work on openatrium):

```
<Directory /var/www/vtiger>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

I also have the same vtiger instance installed on separate CentOS VM LAMP, which is completely working. I've checked config.inc.php and everything seems correct, in fact I also deployed it in Windows through WAMP, which is also working well.

I'm trying it on Ubuntu/Apache2/PHP5.4, one difference I could think of is my CentOS VM is running PHP 5.3, as well as my WAMP.

I can't also seem to turn on `allow_call_time_pass_reference` on php.ini because its missing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you check the http error log for any php error, that may not be displayed because of configuration settings?

Comment: yes I've tried tailing error.log, doesn't show any logs about it at all. btw, if I try accessing using localhost/vtigercrm/install.php it seems to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After countless hours of searching, this patch worked for me. Seems that it was a
[PHP 5.4 issue](http://trac.vtiger.com/cgi-bin/trac.cgi/attachment/ticket/7618/vtigercrm-5.4.0-PHPv54-v2.patch)

See Djante's  [comment](https://forums.vtiger.com/viewtopic.php?t=54593&p=171652)